# Scroll to not letting page move

Tags: javascript

I am trying to trigger scroll when the user reach a specific `div` , however after scrolling to `div`, it is not letting the page to go either up or down. Kind of stucked. Any way to prevent this behaviour so that it only triggers when the user is scrolling from top.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var hT = jQuery('.trigegr').offset().top,
    hH = jQuery('.trigegr').outerHeight(),
    wH = jQuery(window).height(),
    wS = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery("#scroll-too").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 800px;
  background: red;
}

h1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Scroll Down</div>
<h1 class="trigegr">I am The H1</h1>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2 id="scroll-too">I am The H2</h2>
```

Comment: Does `offset().top` of 2000 allow scrolling back up?